# How to save a bitmap as 16-bit in Maxscript?

Tags: bitmap, maxscript, zbuffer

I want to read out the z-buffer of camera, and render it as an image.

I could achieve it with the following code:

```
--Place the z camera
z_cam = freecamera name: "depth"  position:[0.0,0.0,50.0] rotation: (eulertoquat (eulerAngles 0 0 0))

z_name = "mybitmap.png"

--get z buffer          
rbmp = render outputsize:[512,424] channels:#(#zdepth) vfb:off camera: z_cam
z_d = getchannelasmask rbmp #zdepth outputfile:z_name 
z_d.fileName = z_name
save z_d
close z_d
```

However, this will save the image as 24-Bit  Png, with 3 Channels (8 bit each channel). I wish to save it as a grayscale image, where I use 16-Bit for the pixel representation. How can achieve that with max-script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try calling `pngio.setType #gray16` beforehands?

Alternatively, save to exr with a [zDepth channel](http://forums.cgsociety.org/showpost.php?p=7627883&postcount=4) and use that.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I will give it a shoot - however I read in the API that getchannelasmask will always return a 8bit bitmap (http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_9F6ABEE1_0728_4B39_8903_D909634C1304_htm) - so I do not know if this command will alter the behaviour of getchannelasmask

Comment: You can always use a different format that already supports multiple channels, edited the answer accordingly.